# What is the proper way to set a user environment variable in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to schedule a command in a PowerShell script to run using Windows scheduler. This command relies on a user specific environment variable, and since scheduled tasks do not have access to these I have decided to try and just set the variable inside the PowerShell script itself.

The normal environment variable configuration looks like this:

[image]

And in order to replicate this in the script, I tried using:

```
$env:DCRCLIFILE = "C:\Users\pzsr7z\Desktop\DCRCLIFILE.txt"
```

But for some reason the program will not work properly when I set things up this way, even though it works perfectly fine when I run the program using the "normal" user environment variable.

Program execution using the PowerShell initiated environment variable

[image: Image description]

Program execution using the "normal" environment variable:

[image]

Is there anything that I should be doing differently when setting the environment variable in the PowerShell script? I'm not sure why this isn't working. I've verified that the environment variable actually gets created, so it's not like the PowerShell command is failing.

Comment: "since scheduled tasks do not have access to these" - whatever gave you that impression?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart If you set a scheduled task that executes "Get-ChildItem Env:", you will notice in the output that all of the system environment variables are shown while the user specific environment variables are left out. At least that's how it works on the windows 2012 server that I'm running this on

Comment: Under which account is the variable defined, and under which account are you executing the task?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart When I created the variable I just logged in as my normal user and then went to control panel, system, advanced system settings, and set the variable in the "User Variables for pzsr7z" section. For the scheduled task, I just created the task and left the user as the default one which is gxx\pzsr7z. So the same user is both creating and utilizing the variable. 

In case it makes any difference, the scheduled task is running when I'm logged out of the server (once I get this working it will execute once a day)

Comment: I just created a PowerShell script that outputs the content of a user environment variable to a file, and scheduled it to run. The variable was accessible when I used the "run whether user is logged on or not" option. I suspect something else is at play here, as user environment variables should be accessible in scheduled tasks (no reason they shouldn't be).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart If possible, would you be able to log out and let the script run while you are actually logged out and see if you get the same result? I've just tried the same and while it does work properly when I am logged in and running the task on demand, it does not output anything in my log file when I let it run while I'm actually logged out. I'm using the following command for my task: powershell "get-item env:DCRCLIFILE > C:\Users\pzsr7z\Desktop\test.txt"

Comment: Just tested. User-defined environment are available when executed from a scheduled task, even when logged off.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart hmm, ok. Can you think of anything that would be preventing me from accessing those?

Comment: I don't know, unless the accounts are different or the account doesn't have permission to read the file.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Ok, I'll have to do some more research on that. Thanks for your help with testing that though, I appreciate it

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Hey, just letting you know that I found a way to get this working. Instead of calling the dcrcli.exe program directly from powershell, I made a separate batch file that file sets the DCRCILFILE variable and then calls dcrcli after. Not sure why this method did not work in powershell, but it is working correctly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by creating a separate batch file and then setting the DCRCLIFILE variable manually in there, after which I ran the dcrclifile.exe command from within the same batch file.

I'm not sure why things did not work properly when I was attempting to set the variable manually in PowerShell.

Comment: I don't know either. It works fine for me in PowerShell.

Answer (score 27):

```
$env:DCRCLIFILE = "C:\Users\pzsr7z\Desktop\DCRCLIFILE.txt"
```

This only creates a process-level environment variable, which is only visible to, and lasts only as long as, your current PowerShell session.

You need to set a more permanent environment variables (user-level or machine-level) by using the .NET Framework and the SetEnvironmentVariable method:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DCRCLIFILE", "C:\Users\pzsr7z\Desktop\DCRCLIFILE.txt", "User")
```

Comment: Would that take effect immediately though? When I ran that command I had to logout and then log back in before variable became available

Comment: Environment variables are normally only read when a process starts, if you make a change to them you need to restart the process before it can see the changes.

Comment: so what would be the best way to get this working when running things using windows scheduler? I would need to restart powershell after creating the environment variable, but wouldn't I just not be able to access the new variable after the restart since scheduled tasks do not have access to user created environment variables?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Env Var as a Machine Variable?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid that if possible as other people use this server as well, so having this variable globally available would interfere with things when they attempt to run the dcrcli.exe command that was shown in the screenshots in my post

Comment: Have you set the scheduled task to run under the same account you are creating the env var as?